# WPF autofill textblock with ellipsis inside listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

It should be looks like such as on the image[image]

I have an list view with custom `DataTemplate`. I have to autofill all free space with ellipsis in `Description` `TextBlock`.

Do you have any idea how i can do this?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource NodeIconConverter}}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Tittle}" ToolTip="{Binding Description}" />
                <Image Grid.Column="2" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource NodeStatusConverter}}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your DataTemplate like below to have dotted line between space:

```
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource NodeIconConverter}}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Tittle}" ToolTip="{Binding Description}" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Margin="2,5,2,0" Stroke="#FF000000" Height="1" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 4"
                                                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <Image Grid.Column="3" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource NodeStatusConverter}}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```